# How can I write a degree symbol in RMarkdown 2?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I'm writing some code with descriptions using Rmarkdown 2 and knit PDF.

I've been trying many method to write a degree symbol inline:

- Latex package: siunitx's \ang
- Latex package: textcomp's \textdegree
- Latex: \circ

And many possible RMarkdown symbols, such as:

- $$ \textdegree $$ or $\textdegree$

But nothing is working. Is there a way to write a degree symbol in RMarkdown 2 and convert it do PDF?

EDIT (18 AUGUST 2014):

Ok, I found out where is the problem. If you use \circ in normal sentence or first-level list it is ok. But when I try to use \circ in second-level list - it's not working.

[image]

Comment: did you google latex degree?

Comment: yes, of course - and I find there that \textdegree or \circ option; but it's not working for me in inline RMarkdown2 -> PDF file

Comment: Never say "its not working for me". Say how its not working. Error message? No symbol at all? Symbol in the wrong place? Also, include your non-working source.

Comment: Spacedman, of course you're right. I've included some explanation.

Comment: The second level list is typeset in typewriter font - is that how it does it even if you don't have some $stuff$ in it? I'll have to look at the intermediate TeX file to see exactly what its doing...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was with RMarkdown converting nested lists. On this page http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html you can find sentence:

> The nested list must be indented four spaces or one tab

Although, using the tab could be a problem. When using four spaces - it works:

```
* Let's turn this round 360$^\circ$
    + Let's turn this round 360$^\circ$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using \circ works for me, RStudio, knit to pdf:

```
Let's turn this round 360$^\circ$
```

[image: degree symbol]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotmath`'s `degree`, e.g.

```
plot(1, xlab=expression(4*degree))
```